# Natural language interpreter in Prolog does not work

Tags: prolog

I'm having a problem in Prolog. I'm trying to write a converter that converts simple english sentences into commands in Prolog.
Im trying to create a text adventure game using the tutorial [here](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a15nlang.php).

My problem is this: After starting the main command loop, when entering a sentence and hitting the "enter" button, Prolog will simply jump into the next line, seemingly not executing the command at all. It does not matter how often I enter a full-stop. Before using this language converter, everything worked just fine and the game was playable using commands. The problem must be within this part of the code. More precisely, I think the part for reading lines or the `get_command(X)` function are most likely not working.
I'm using SWI-Polog by the way, in case that is of importance (some people add this info to their questions).
Since I can't spot the mistake myself, I will try to post the relevant code.

First the main command loop:

```
command_loop:- 
  write('Welcome to Nani Search'), nl,
  look,nl,
  repeat,
  write('>nani> '),
  get_command(X),
  do(X), nl,
  end_condition(X).
```

And now the converter (the `get_command(X)` function is at the very bottom):

```
% Natural language converter

command([V], InList):- verb(V, InList-[]).

verb(look, [look|X]-X).
verb(look, [look,around|X]-X).
verb(look, [glotz,ma,alde|X]-X).
verb(list_possessions, [inventory|X]-X).
verb(end, [end|X]-X).
verb(end, [quit|X]-X).
verb(end, [good,bye|X]-X).

command([V,O], InList) :-
  verb(Object_Type, V, InList-S1),
  object(Object_Type, O, S1-[]).

verb(place, goto, [go,to|X]-X).
verb(place, goto, [go|X]-X).
verb(place, goto, [move,to|X]-X).

 % Exceptions for rooms with two words
verb(place, goto, [X|Y]-[X|Y]):- room(X).
verb(place, goto, [dining,room|Y]-[dining,room|Y]).

verb(thing, take, [take|X]-X).
verb(thing, drop, [drop|X]-X).
verb(thing, drop, [put|X]-X).
verb(thing, turn_on, [turn,on|X]-X).
verb(thing, turn_off, [turn,off|X]-X).

object(Type, N, S1-S3) :-
  det(S1-S2),
  noun(Type, N, S2-S3).
object(Type, N, S1-S2) :-
  noun(Type, N, S1-S2).

det([the|X]- X).
det([a|X]-X).
det([an|X]-X).

 % Exceptions for rooms with two words
noun(place, R, [R|X]-X):- room(R).
noun(place, 'dining room', [dining,room|X]-X).

 % Exceptions for things with two words
noun(thing, T, [T|X]-X):- location(object(T,_),_).
noun(thing, T, [T|X]-X):- have(object(T,_)).
noun(thing, 'washing machine', [washing,machine|X]-X).

noun(thing, flashlight, [light|X]-X):- have(object(flashlight,_)).
noun(thing, light, [light|X]-X).

% read a line of words from the user

read_list(L) :-
  write('> '),
  read_line(CL),
  wordlist(L,CL,[]), !.

read_line(L) :-
  get0(C),
  buildlist(C,L).

buildlist(13,[]) :- !.
buildlist(C,[C|X]) :-
  get0(C2),
  buildlist(C2,X).

wordlist([X|Y]) --> word(X), whitespace, wordlist(Y).
wordlist([X]) --> whitespace, wordlist(X).
wordlist([X]) --> word(X).
wordlist([X]) --> word(X), whitespace.

word(W) --> charlist(X), {name(W,X)}.

charlist([X|Y]) --> chr(X), charlist(Y).
charlist([X]) --> chr(X).

chr(X) --> [X],{X>=48}.

whitespace --> whsp, whitespace.
whitespace --> whsp.

whsp --> [X], {X<48}.

% Return a command

get_command(C) :-
  read_list(L),
  command(CL,L),
  C =..  CL, !.
get_command(_) :-
  write('I don''t understand'), nl, fail.
```

And finally, the do-function from the command loop:

```
do(goto(X)):-goto(X),!.
do(go(X)):-goto(X),!.
do(take(X)):-take(X),!.
do(put(X,Y)):-put(X),!.
do(turn_on(X)):-turn_on(X),!.
do(turn_off(X)):-turn_off(X),!.
do(inventory):-inventory,!.
do(list_things(X)):-list_things(X),!.
do(look):-look,!.
do(end).
do(_) :-
 write('Invalid command').
```

By converting the natural language sentences into these commands, the program is supposed to start the respective function. It is supposed to work like this: When you enter `go to the office.` the converter is supposed to transform the frase into the command `goto(office)`. When one writes `take the flashlight` it is supposed to convert it to `take(flashlight)` . When one writes `look around`. it should be converted to `look`. The converted command should then be send to the command loop and be executed via do(X) (As seen in the do-function, X must be command like `goto(office)`.
I hope it is clear what my question is.

I also made a trace. The command loop is being started normally. This is what happens after the end of the command loop (the `write('>nani> ')` still being part of it).

```
 Call: (7) write('>nani> ') ? creep
>nani> 
   Exit: (7) write('>nani> ') ? creep
   Call: (7) get_command(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (8) read_list(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (9) write('> ') ? creep
> 
   Exit: (9) write('> ') ? creep
   Call: (9) read_line(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (10) get0(_G3903) ? creep
|:
```

Then I'm able to enter a new command. By simply pressing the Enter button without giving any input, it will always do the following:

```
   Exit: (10) get0(10) ? creep
   Call: (10) buildlist(10, _G3904) ? creep
   Call: (11) get0(_G3906) ? creep
|:
```

This is being repeated whenever I hit enter. When I enter a random letter or multiple letters before pressing enter, the value of the first get0 will change, but nothing else.

Depending on which letters I write there sometimes is a different result though. Here are two examples:
For example when I try writing *dsf*, this will happen:

```
|: dsf

   Exit: (10) get0(100) ? skip
   Call: (10) buildlist(100, _G3904) ? fail
   Fail: (9) read_line(_G3903) ? creep
   Fail: (8) read_list(_G3903) ? creep
   Redo: (7) get_command(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (8) write('I don\'t understand') ? creep
I don't understand
   Exit: (8) write('I don\'t understand') ? creep
   Call: (8) nl ? creep
   Exit: (8) nl ? creep
᠀   Call: (8) fail ? creep
   Fail: (8) fail ? creep
   Fail: (7) get_command(_G3903) ? creep
   Redo: (7) repeat ? creep
   Exit: (7) repeat ? creep
   Call: (7) write('>nani> ') ? creep
>nani> 
   Exit: (7) write('>nani> ') ? creep
   Call: (7) get_command(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (8) read_list(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (9) write('> ') ? creep
> 
   Exit: (9) write('> ') ? creep
   Call: (9) read_line(_G3903) ? creep
   Call: (10) get0(_G3903) ? creep
|:
```

Other input like *apg* will have the following result:

```
|: apg

Exit: (17) get0(97) ? print
   Exit: (17) get0(97) ? goals
 [17] get0(97)
 [16] buildlist(10, [10|_G3915])
 [15] buildlist(10, [10, 10|_G3915])
 [14] buildlist(10, [10, 10, 10|_G3915])
 [13] buildlist(10, [10, 10, 10, 10|_G3915])
   Exit: (17) get0(97) ? creep
   Call: (17) buildlist(97, _G3915) ? creep
   Call: (18) get0(_G3927) ? creep
```

And when entering longer commands, random or also something like `go to the office.`, the program will shut down completely, without a comment. This shutdown only happens while the trace is activated. When it is not, commands like `go to the office.` will, again, simply make the program jump to the next line, seemingly not doing anything.
What might also be interesting is the fact that, after starting the command loop, the program takes a long time to shut down. The following message is being displayed:

```
Waiting for Prolog. Close again to force termination ..
```

Since I'm really new to Prolog, I'm not quite sure how to interpret this. To me the reaction to the random letters as input is competely random. Maybe someone else has a clue.

I would apreciate it a lot, if someone could help me out. I hope it's not too big of a mistake.

Regards :)

Comment: Euh, can you provide an example what your program is supposed to do for some input? It's a bit hard to debug a program without test input...

Comment: Yes, I can! It is supposed to work like this: When you enter `go to the office.` the converter is supposed to transform the frase into the command `goto(office).`. When one writes `take the flashlight` it is supposed to convert it to `take(flashlight).` . When one writes `look around.` it should be converted to `look.`. The converted command should then be send to the command loop and executed via `do(X)` (X must be command like `goto(office)`, since it is structured like this: `do(goto(X)):-goto(X),!.` I apologize if my question is too confusing.. :(

Comment: I added the "do" functions in the original message. Hopefully it gets clearer what the program is supposed to do now. And again, I apologize if I'm not giving sufficient information!

Comment: Now that you've given examples of what it *should* do, what is it *actually* doing, and *what have you tried so far* to debug it?

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, after starting the command loop I'm unable to enter any more commands. Whether I write a command like `goto(office)` or whether I write a full sentence like `go to the office.` does not matter, it will never execute the command but just jump to a new line. Full-stops after the commands does not make a change either. It seems like it nevers stops waiting for input.

Comment: Did you try doing a `trace`?

Comment: Since the end of the sentence seems not to be sufficient as a stop signal, I tried to implement a rule after which a full-stop in the end of a sentence tells the program that it is the end of the input, but all my attempts failed. I also tried using `read_line_to_codes` to solve this, but I couldn't find a working solution either. The only "progress" I made is when I made bad mistakes in my attemps to alter the code, then the program at least realized the input came to an end and wrote _I don't understand_ , showing me that get_command had failed (due to the mistake as expected).

Comment: I edited the original post, lurker, now giving some of the trace results. Unfortunately I really don't know what that is supposed to mean. It just seems comepletely random to me. Hopefully this will help. If some more information is needed, I of course can provide it.

Comment: What part of the trace appears *random*?. It shows you exactly where it's gone through your code. When you press Enter, the `get0(10)` shows it read ASCII code 10 (ASCII code for line feed). In your other example, the first `get0(100)` shows that it read a code `100`, which is the letter `d` in ASCII from your `dsf` input. You just need to read it a step at a time and look at your code to see where it's going.

Comment: why are you not using a standard DCG, instead of hard-coding one ? Will be far easier... (for instance, are you sure `verb(place, goto, [X|Y]-[X|Y]):- room(X).` is doing what you expect ?)